# ReflectionException - Class does not exist after creating http middleware on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, middleware

I just want to add HTTP middleware for filtering user role but I get this error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 779: Class create:comptable
>   does not exist
>
> ```
> in Container.php line 779
> at ReflectionClass->__construct('create:comptable') in Container.php line 779
> at Container->build('create:comptable', array()) in Container.php line 659
> at Container->make('create:comptable', array()) in Application.php line 644
> at Application->make('create:comptable') in Pipeline.php line 124
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
> at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
> at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
> at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
> at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
> at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
> at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
> at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
> at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
> at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
> at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
> at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
> at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
> at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
> at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
> at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
> at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
> at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
> at require_once('C:\wamp\www\Medecin2016\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
> ```

And this is what I do:
Create middlerware "create":

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CreateInfos {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$comptable)
    {
        $User = $request->user();
        return ($User->hasRole($comptable)) ? $next($request) : response(view('errors.503'),401);
    }

}
```

Set a short name by editing Kernel.php file:

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'create' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CreateInfos',
        'update' => 'App\Http\Middleware\UpdateInfos',
        'delete' => 'App\Http\Middleware\DeleteInfos',
    ];

}
```

And adding the middleware to Routes file:

```
Route::get('profile/diplomes'           ,['middleware'=>'create:comptable','uses'=>'ProfileFormsController@getFormDiplomes']);
Route::post('profile/diplomes'          ,['middleware'=>'create:comptable','uses'=>'ProfileFormsController@postDiplomes']);
Route::post('profile/update/diplomes'   ,['middleware'=>'create:comptable','uses'=>'ProfileFormsController@updateDiplomes']);
Route::post('profile/delete/diplomes'   ,['middleware'=>'create:comptable','uses'=>'ProfileFormsController@deleteDiplomes']);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve your issue, but you could merge these `create`, `update` and `delete` middlewares into one `permission` middleware, since you're only checking if the user has permission by name anyway.

Comment: Try running `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*`.

Comment: I'm on laravel 5 ? what is this command ?

Comment: That's fine, it removes the cached data from your installation. It tends to help with weird issues.

Comment: doesn't work I'm on windows

Answer (score 0):

After change middleware from routes to controller and add this to it:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CreateInfos;

class ProfileFormsController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('create');
    }
```